# Python POST encoding and formatting

Tags: python, post, character-encoding, urllib

I'm sending a POST request using urllib with Python.

I used Charles to see the POST that usually gets sent and now i'm trying to send the same thing using urllib.

**This is what should be sent according to charles:**

{"stuff_values":{"description":"This is description","somestuff":[{"thing":"hello","title":"i love cookies"}]}}

**This is what i'm sending:**

stuff_values=%7B%27description%27%3A+%27This+is+description%27%2C+%27somestuff%27%3A+%5B%7B%27thing%27%3A+%27hello%27%2C+%27title%27%3A+%27i+love+cookies%27%7D%5D%7D

**This is part of my code:**

```
values = {
"stuff_values":{
"description":"this is description",
"somestuff" : [{"thing":"hello",
"title":"i love cookies"}]}
}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers = headers)
```

Could someone help me figure this out? I'm guessing i have a problem with the encoding part but also with formatting the rest properly.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You are encoding your data, and that is the result of doing so. What is wrong?

Comment: Well. I only encoded it because the documentation said i should ;). I've tried a few other encodings but none seems to net me the result i'm aiming for (what should be sent). I'm asking if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The right direction for what? What do you want? Your first example is not encoded at all.

Comment: I thought i made it fairly clear that i'm trying to send the same data as in the first bolded part. Thank you anyway. I think i got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data = str(values)
```

instead. `urlencode` is converting certain characters to %xx escapes.